# $user->uid is false even when logged in

Tags: users

I have this code:

```
global $user;

if (!$user->uid) {
  drupal_set_message("You must log in to view this content.");
  drupal_goto('node/153', array('query'=>drupal_get_destination()));
}
```

`$user->uid` evaluates correctly when logged in as admin and editor, but users that don't have admin or editor roles have NO UID. Immediately before and after this code resolves to false, I visit site-root/user, and sure enough, I'm logged in.

What setting causes this?  I've used this code many times to see if a user is logged in, and I can't find any setting that would cause this behavior.

Comment: any clues from print_r($user)?

Comment: try to clear cache. do you have any special drupal module installed that alters user object

Comment: That's impossibruuuu..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not yet clear on all the reasons, but the [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) module was causing all users that weren't selected to go on https to return as null.  Even `user_is_logged_in()` was returning false.

Moving a user to https upon login returned these functions' behavior back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
global $user;

if(!$user->uid) {
  drupal_set_message("You must log in to view this content.");
  drupal_goto('node/153', array('query'=>drupal_get_destination()) );
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I do have `global $user` in my code, I forgot to state that in my question.  I'll update it.

Comment: Maybe you can try
`global $user; drupal_set_message(print_r($user, 1));` to see the content of the `$user` variable.